# Функция DeleteAll в PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сбросить игровую статистику по нажатию на кнопку, но удаление не происходит. Как правильно это сделать?

```
using ...

public class Stats : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float money, xBoost, addon, DOPM, DOPAuto;
    private SaveGame SG = new SaveGame();
    // etc

    public void CancelAll()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

сохранение

```
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
{
    if (pause)
    {
        SG.DOPAuto = DOPAuto;
        SG.DOPM = DOPM;
        SG.money = money;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("SAVE", JsonUtility.ToJson(SG));
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Загрузка сохранений

```
private void Awake()
{

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("SAVE"))
    {
        SG = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("SAVE"));
        DOPAuto = SG.DOPAuto;
        DOPM = SG.DOPM;
        money = SG.money;
    }
}
```

Класс SaveGame

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveGame
{
   public float money, DOPM, DOPAuto;
}
```

Comment: а вы, случайно, не статическую переменную записываете туда?

Comment: @M.Green нет, все переменные не статичны. Эта функция работает нормально только если я ее пишу в Awake

Comment: Можете код всего класса вставить в вопрос? Мне кажется, проблема не в том, что ключи не удаляются, а в том, как вы их используете

Comment: @M.Green добавил)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, OnApplicationPause вызывается и при выходе из приложения. Т.е. при сбросе статистики вы не обнуляете файл SaveGame и в итоге при выходе из игры этот файл опять сохраняется в PlayerPrefs.

Comment: @M.Green так оно не обнуляет значения при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Попробуйте получить значения сразу после удаления. Они всё еще там будут?

Comment: @M.Green да, в конcоли проверил -- не сбрасывает значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас статистика игры не static - вы создаете один объект SG и всю иру с ним работаете? Если так, и вам "Нужно сбросить игровую статистику по нажатию на кнопку", то у вас в `public void CancelAll()` сбрасываются только PlayerPrefs, а статистика то у вас находится в SG. Вам надо тогда обнулить переменные. Как то так:

```
public void CancelAll()
        {
          //ставите значения по умолчанию, что у вас, например 0f
           SG.money = 0f;
           SG.xBoost = 0f;
           SG.addon = 0f;
           SG.DOPM = 0f;
           SG.DOPAuto = 0f;
           PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
           PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, чуть изменил и получилось то что хотел :-)

Comment: @zip_file, если данный ответ ответил на ваш вопрос - отметьте его, как правильный, или если вы решили вопрос самостоятельно - оформите свое решение, как ответ.